# Should I worry about a pipe getting overflown?

Tags: linux, unix, ipc, pipe

There are two processes (parent and child) communicating through a pipe. The parent is waiting for its child to exit, then reads data from the read end of the pipe. The child may produce quite a lot of output. Is it possible for the pipe to fail because of too much unread data in it and lose some of the child's output?

Comment: Is this some reason you are doing it this way? It seems unnecessary to use a pipe if the processes only communicate in one direction at one time.  Why not just have the parent generate a random file name and have the child write to that file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to worry about that: On a standard 2.6 or 3.0 Kernel the pipe buffer is 64k - so the first process will block on write, if the buffer runs full.

If on the other hand this is too little, use `buffer` between the two workers, which has a configurable memory size

Comment: Wait a second, this exactly means that I *do* have to worry about that, because the second process will never exit if the buffer is full, and the first process will never read anything from the buffer until the second one exits. It's a deadlock!

Comment: although it's true that the writing process will block if the pipe is full, neither the version of Linux nor the size of the pipe buffer effect that behavior.

Comment: @DanD. I beg to disagree: In the 2.4 kernels there was something like "scalable pipes" (I forgot the exact name), that could be ioctl'd to other buffer sizes.

Comment: @EugenRieck that doesn't effect the process's blocking if it attempts to write to a full pipe, it only provides a way for the process to make the pipe buffer larger or smaller.

Comment: You can also set O_NONBLOCK on the pipe fd and the child's writes will fail instead of block when PIPEBUF is hit

Comment: @DanD. It does effect the process's blocking: You can (could) theoretically create a buffer size equal to the possible address space - so no blocking, but a crash ;-)

Comment: @frankc This will work, but it needs the first program to be reworked to handle (and retry) failed writes. Nit sure if that's feasable in the OQ

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the pipe fills up the child process blocks and you get a deadlock.

This is a problem encountered also in python, see the Popen.wait() warning at [1], section 17.1.2; they used the communicate method to avoid the issue.

[1] http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html